# Running a real WIndows 10 guest installation in VirtualBox on Debian host

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, partitioning, debian

I'm trying to run a real/physical Debian installation in Virtualbox on Windows 10. I found this tutorial and I take it as guide :

[Running a real Windows install in VirtualBox on Linux](http://greenash.net.au/thoughts/2016/02/running-a-real-windows-install-in-virtualbox-on-linux/)

At a certain point,the author says to do :

```
sudo VBoxManage internalcommands createrawvmdk -filename "/path/to/win8.vmdk" -rawdisk /dev/sda -partitions 1,4,5
```

So,on the debian partition I did :

```
sudo VBoxManage internalcommands createrawvmdk -filename "/media/Data/debian.vmdk" -rawdisk /dev/sda -partitions 5,6
```

where sda5 and sda6 are the partitions where debian is installed. It has created two files :

deb.vmdk
deb-pt.vmdk

and it worked. I can boot the real partition of Debian with Virtualbox on another installation of Debian. But,since I'm on Windows 10,I can't use the command exactly as it is,but I need to know what's the correct way to do the same but on Windows. On windows 10 I've installed the ext2fs file system and I can access the linux partition in read and write mode. So,if we assume that the linux partition where I want to run Debian is on the drive G ; the swap partition is on the drive H and the vmdk files are on the drive J,how can I ask to VirtualBox to use these drives ? Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Ummm... why not just use the VirtualBox GUI ?  Create a new machine, DONT add a hard drive to it, and then once it is created edit the configuration and point the hard drive controllers to the files you want

Comment: how ? can you explain a little better ?

Comment: I found the answer that I was looking for here : https://romaimperator.com/?p=29 ; this command has been useful : VBoxManage internalcommands createrawvmdk -filename "f:\deby.vmdk" -rawdisk "\\.\PhysicalDrive0",but anyway,it didn't work,and you can see why going here : https://ibb.co/n5CNFk and https://ibb.co/jaLngQ